# Динамический двумерный массив: значение типа "int *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "int"

Tags: c++

Стоит задача, дан двумерный динамический массив, посчитать сумму в столбцах, ну компилятор ругается на этом месте `sum = sum + arr[j];` пишет значение типа "int *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "int"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать.
Непосредственно сам код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int N;
    int M;
    int sum;
    cout << "Vvedite N - kolvo strock" << endl;
    cin >> N; 
    cout << "Vvedite M - kolvo stolb" << endl;
    cin >> M;

    int **arr = new int*[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i] = new int[M];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 100;
            cout  << arr[i][j]<<"\t";
            sum = sum + arr[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << sum << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        delete[] arr[i];

    delete[] arr;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас имеется двумерный массив, для получения значения массива вы должны использовать индексацию по каждой размерности, те так

```
sum = sum + arr[i][j];
```

В вашем случае, вы получаете указатель на массив, то есть `int*`

Answer (score 3):

Вы присваиваете переменной типа int значение укказателя на int

```
sum = sum + arr[j];
```

используйте

```
sum = sum + arr[i][j];
```

Comment: @tillin Это он считает сумму всего массива, верно?

Comment: @Mr.Flatman Да, всего массива. Вопрос был об ошибке компиляции, я правильно понял?

Comment: @tillin Да, вопрос стоял об ошибки компилятора, теперь пойду разбираться как реализовать подсчет суммы столбцов.